# Priority on words in a paragraph

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex formula for test a paragraph that have words in priority.

Example text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

I have below regex for looking words in a text but there is no priority on these words:

```
/(?=.*consectetur)(?=.*dolor)/
```

How can I set a priority for this regex? thnx guys

Comment: What do you mean by "priority"?

Comment: @Peaceful for example; regext first looking for "consectetur" then looking for "dolor" after  "consectetur" in a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/(?=.*consectetur)(?=.*dolor)/` regex matches the two substrings regardless of their order in the string.

You need to use

```
/consectetur.*dolor/
```

if you want `dolor` to appear after `consectetur`. Swap the values in the pattern to reverse the order.

You might also want to replace `.` with `[\s\S]` to also match across lines. Or use a DOTALL modifier if available.

If you know that the distance between the two values is not that big, use a lazy qunatifier `*?` instead of a greedy `*`.